# Как использовать в PHP OOP результат функции в других функциях?

Tags: php, ооп

Например, мне нужно одно и то же значение передать в разные функции одного и того же класса.

```
public function rand(){
    $rnd=mt_rand(1,10);
    return $rnd;
}
public function first(){
  return  $this->rand();
}
public function two(){
   return $this->rand();
}
```

Comment: вы тут не передаете значение в функции, а возвращаете из функций

Comment: Функции ferst и twhoo должны возвращать разные значения?

Comment: @Naumov нет должны быть одинаковые значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала нужно разобраться, что такое $rnd и где он используется. Допустим он используется в 2-х функциях одного класса и является общим для одного и только одного объекта. Тогда данная переменная должна быть Не статическим полем этого класса.

```
...
private $rnd;
...
public function generateRand(){
   $this->rnd=mt_rand(1,10);
}
```

Допустим $rnd меняется в каждой функции и её сохранение в переменную не целесообразно. Тогда метод по идее должен будет выглядеть так:

`public function rand(){
    return mt_rand(1,10);
}`

Но что такое метод? Метод это функция класса, которая обрабатывает поля класса. В данном случае никакие поля класса не обрабатываются, просто будет получение рандомного числа поэтому метод должен быть статический:

```
public static function generateRand(){
   return mt_rand(1,10);
}
```

И вызов его соответствующий:

```
public function first(){ //ferst
  return  self::generateRand();
}
public function second(){ //twhoo
  return  self::generateRand();
}
```

Ну и если полученное рандомное значение должно быть одно для всех объектов, тогда используем static

---

*Есть неплохая книга объясняющая основы ООП. Называется она "Объектно ориентированное мышление", вот [ссылка](http://sd.blackball.lv/library/Objektno-orientirovannoe_myshlenie_(2014).pdf) на неё*

Comment: дело в том что нужно получать одно и тоже значение но при таком раскладе получается значение null 
  private $rnd;
    
    public function rand() {
            $this->rand = mb_rand(1,10);
    }

    public function ferst(){
    $this->rnd;
    }
    public function twhoo(){
        $this->rnd;
    }

Comment: Так Вы наверное свою функцию rand не вызываете.  То есть порядок такой: сгенерировать generateRand или rand, как у Вас, потом уже вызывать $this->rnd в методах first и two.

Comment: За книгу спасибо.

Comment: А как вызвать функцию внутри класа??, За книгу спасибо Да действительно я не вызывал функцию rand()

Comment: Вот залил http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e10c16a64ce5fbf16af23866575f1609b8962a3f

Comment: Ну, из класса Вам стоит вызывать её  скорее всего в конструкторе.  Тогда этот метод должен быть приватный.

Comment: вот как то так http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c502616e1548094f432ed48be0acaaa1c67c2290

Answer (score 3):

Запоминать значение внутри класса, и если значение уже есть - выводить его, если нет - получить.

```
class X {
   private $rand;

   public function rand() {
       if (is_null($this->rand)) {
           $this->rand = mb_rand(1,10);
       }
       return $this->rand;
   }
}
```

Похожее поведение можно реализовать в функции

```
function myrand() {
   static $rand;
   if (is_null($rand)) {
       $rand = mb_rand(1,10);
   }
   return $rand;
}
```

Comment: Столько правок )) Я думаю, стоит у автора уточнить суть вопроса )

Comment: @Ivan Bolnikh а как передать в функции one() и twoo()

Comment: @Дима Перильман также как в вопросе `$this->rand();` или `myrand();`